# C/C++ local variable nuance

Tags: c, arrays, performance

Okay, before I post this question, I know for sure there are these so-called 'pros' in this community accusing me of premature optimization. Let me be clear: I want to be sure what I am exactly writing, even if it is such a nuance at stack level inside a function.
I have a multidimensional array, and I know that in order to access the data, you need to access these index variables and then the arrays themselves, taking up a lot of time. So I did this:

```
 char* ref = gdata.mapnames[game.maptype][game.map];
 size_t a = strlen(ref) - 4;
 ref[a] = '\0';
 strcpy(temppath, ref);
 ref[a] = '.';`
```

I 'wrapped' the multidimensional array up in a simple local variable functioning as a pointer. Since I have to access the same array multiple times, could this method save up lookup time and therefore runtime speed? In theory of course, since nowadays the processors are so fast you wont see any difference, unless I write bigger apps needing this. Multidimensional arrays arent bad habits right?

Comment: Multidimensional array certainly isn't a bad habit.  However, i have no idea what you are trying to speed up.

Comment: it is a good idea to cache the result of array element lookup in this case. some do call common sence a premature optimization, do not be discorouged with that.

Comment: Why are you doing `ref[a] = '\0'`? `strlen` will work only if `ref` points to a string, i.e., a null-terminated character array, else you will run into error.

Comment: Your code looks like premature un-optimization to me. Why do you scan `ref` twice instead of once? Why do you do two redundant writes to `ref[a]` ?

Comment: You are not optimizing anything. You are focusing on making sure the compiler isn't stupid (which they aren't anymore) instead of focusing on making your algorithm better(that which the compiler cannot optimise for you)
Optimize your algorithm, then compile with -O3 or whatever is max optimisation. Then check the generated Assembly if you think that such optimization isn't already taking place.

Comment: guys, this is just an algorithm to display a filename without its extensions but yet not altering the filename at the end so loading goes easily... is this a bad algorithm? I think it works nicely in its circumstances...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `strcpy`, it's dangerous, use [**strncpy**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) instead. Regarding your question, the compiler will do all this things for you, don't worry about looking up anything.

Comment: For me, *dangerous* sounds a bit harsh. If the invariants are satisfied (there's enough space), it's safe.

Comment: strcpy and strncpy do rather different things, one isn't a straight swap for the other. Given that he is concerned about micro-optimization, recommending a function that might write thousands of extra bytes doesn't make sense. There's nothing at all wrong with `strcpy` if you know the lengths of source and destination.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, mapnames[i] may actually be a function call, due to operator overloading. In other words, quite complex code could be executed. In C this is just pointer arithmetic.
Whether your compiler optimizes this depends on a lot of things, including platform, version and variable qualifiers. The only way to be sure is to check the assembly output.
In this case using a temporary variable is much more readable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

With a halfway competent optimizer this will make absolutely no difference in speed and may produce absolutely identical machine code (unless you're dealing with threaded code and an array that is visible to more than one thread), but using the temporary variable makes the code both easier to write and easier to read. However, I would rewrite much of the rest of the code block, to something like:

```
ssize_t a = strlen(ref) - 4;
if( a < 0 ) a = 0;
if( a >= sizeof( temppath ) ) a = sizeof(temppath)-1; /* assumes temppath is an array */
strncpy( temppath, ref, a );
temppath[a] = 0;
```

Explanations: if( ref ) is less than 4 bytes in length, a size_t will wind up as a very large number, since size_t is unsigned. ssize_t is signed and thus it will be a negative value. Next, do bounds checking. I use the strncpy with null terminator because it's usually best to avoid modifying string inputs if you don't have to.

*edit* actually, unless the optimizer knows that the contents of the array are immutable over the course of the function, or gdata.mapnames[game.maptype][game.map] is actually a char[] array, it can't cache ref, but it may be able to cache &gdata.mapnames[game.maptype][game.map].

Comment: Thank you for the observations!

Comment: However, ref is ensured to be at least 4 bytes since another function loads the arrays ONLY from file with extension .map, already 4 chars (bytes) guaranteed. I wrote that function myself, so I am pretty sure.